# How to draw a line between two points from a scatterplot selected via a pick event

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, mouseevent

This is a matplotlib and pick_event problem. We have tried to set a first and a second picks of two points from a scatterplot. However we have not yet found how to do so via a pick_event. Also we wish to create multiple lines between points from a scatterplot. Thank you for your assistance!

We hope to find a part of program that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that creates a line when you click on two points of a scatter plot. Is that what you are looking for?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backend_bases import PickEvent
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib import axes

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x = rand(100)
y = rand(100)
ax.scatter(x, y, picker=True)

buffer = []
line_params = dict(color='black')


def onpick(event: PickEvent, buffer: list, ax: axes, line_params: dict):
    if isinstance(event.artist, PathCollection):
        i = event.ind
        buffer.append((x[i][0], y[i][0]))
    if len(buffer) == 2:
        print(f"Creating line with points {buffer}")
        array = np.array(buffer)
        ax.plot(array[:, 0], array[:, 1], **line_params)
        plt.draw()
        buffer.clear()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', lambda event: onpick(event, buffer, ax, line_params))
plt.show(block=True)
```

[image]